# Is there a way to make it easier to talk to higher rep / regular users in chat?

Tags: feature-request

In Physics SE and Math SE, there is a healthy group of people who use the chatroom. They usually aren't there to answer questions but just bounce ideas around because they love the subject. This has the benefit that  users can learn, engage, and avoid asking silly questions by asking a bit about their appropriatenes/suitability before posting.

The problem is no one uses the econ chat regularly. So to contact someone is very difficult. Whereas I can ping the regulars in physics and math chat, I can't do so here.

Is there a way we could like have some sort of "opt in" feature so if you wanted to be contactable through chat you could be? This would be instead of just the 2 day limit. The problem with the 2 day limit is that it impairs any chatting at all because the room isn't getting used much. So if there aren't regulars, you can't contact anyone worth talking to. With an opt in feature, users could use chat with more irregular frequencies and it might help make it more lively.

Comment: Excellent question. I think the reaction it has triggered is very telling.

Comment: As this site is easily addictive, I'm trying to not be permanently active/online. So, while not being present in the chat all the time, Im looking at the chat once a day. Not sure about others, but you can ping me there.